# Calibration the instruments

Tags: signal-analysis

The Measurement systems and instruments are frequently calibrated.
Do anyone know the reason behind different calibrations. 
I have read that the measurement uncertainty increases with every step in the calibration chain..Is it right and why is that?

Comment: It is all discussed in great detail in this freely available source: EURACHEM/CITAC Guide, “Quantifying Uncertainty in Analytical Measurement”, 3rd Ed., 2012. Just search for it online. It has worked examples and lots more.

Comment: Thanks for you answer